# jQuery onClick pass a variable via GET to URL and load that URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know how to pass variables through AJAX calls via onClick to a PHP file and asynchronously loading the results on the initial page.

I now need to analogously pass a variable via onClick to a PHP file but I need to open a new window or redirect the whole page with the passed variable. The URL needs to contain the variable, so that the query/results can be "statically" sent to someone, like 'xyz.php?var=xyz'

I thought I could do something like this

```
 $("#submit").click(function(event) {                
        var category_id = {};
        category_id['linkgen'] = $("#linkgen").val();
        $.ajax({    
          type: "GET",
          url: "generatedlink.php",        
          dataType: "html",   
          data: category_id,         
          success: function(response){ 
             window.open('generatedlink.php');  
          }
        }); 
      });
```

This only opens 'generatedlink.php'. I actually want what is passed via AJAX, i.e. 'generatedlink.php?linkgen=blabla' onClick in a new window/reloaded page! I'd very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try: without ajax call

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {                
    window.open('generatedlink.php?inkgen='+$("#linkgen").val());    
});
```